# Export all symbols from dlls on windows (including Qt metaobjects)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, qt6

I am using Qt 6.5 and cmake and I am looking for a way to export all symbols from my dlls, without needing to manually add macros to them. I am aware that there is `WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` for cmake, but this doesn't seem to export metaobjects, thus giving me errors that tell me that linking those failed.
Is there a solution to this that also links the Qt metaobjects?

Comment: Try add the header file of your object within the .dll to the .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that the cmake documentation mentions that global and static symbols are not exported automatically with the `WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` option. This explains why only the static meta objects are not exported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> , but this doesn't seem to export metaobjects, thus giving me errors that tell me that linking those failed. Is there a solution to this that also links the Qt metaobjects?

This has nothing to do with exports. You need to have the generated `moc_<filename>.cpp` included in your `<filename>.cpp` or at least be part of the compilation. Be sure that `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` is true/on.